ELPA library installation problem, clang: error: no input files
I am compiling elpa (EIGENVALUE SOLVERS FOR PETAFLOP APPLICATIONS) library on macos 14.5. I make a sub-directory named "build" in its main directory and in the sub-directory, configure succeeded. However,make failed. And there are so many errors like
  F90 USE  [elpa2_print_kernels] ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 MOD  [elpa2_print_kernels] ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 USE  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 MOD  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 USE  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 MOD  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 USE  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_2stage_all_kernels_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
clang: error: no input files
  F90 MOD  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_2stage_all_kernels_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
clang: error: no input files
.............

My configure flags are
CC=mpicc FC=mpif90 CXX=mpicxx ../configure SCALAPACK_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/scalapack/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openmpi/lib" SCALAPACK_FCFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/scalapack/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openmpi/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig" CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC -march=native" FCFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC -march=native" CXXFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC -march=native"

And make V=1 gives more detailed errors information like
cpp -P -traditional -Wall -Werror -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -o /dev/stdout ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90 | grep -i -o '^ *use [^ ,!:]*' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u > src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels-elpa2_print_kernels.use_mods_elpa2_print_kernels.o
clang: error: no input files
cpp -P -traditional -Wall -Werror -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -o /dev/stdout ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90 | grep -i -o '^ *module [^!]*' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -v "\<procedure\>\|\<intrinsic\>" > src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels-elpa2_print_kernels.def_mods_elpa2_print_kernels.o || true
clang: error: no input files
cpp -P -traditional -Wall -Werror -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -o /dev/stdout ../test/Fortran/test.F90 | grep -i -o '^ *use [^ ,!:]*' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u > test/Fortran/validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts-test.use_mods_validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts.o
clang: error: no input files

As suggested by Mr.Gilles Gouaillardet, I have removed -o /dev/stdout in fdep/fortran_dependencies.mk ,then run autogen.sh and configure again. The above errors are resolved. Some new errors appear, like
  F90 USE  [elpa2_print_kernels] ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90
  F90 MOD  [elpa2_print_kernels] ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90
  F90 USE  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
../test/Fortran/test.F90:358:14: error: empty character constant [-Werror,-Winvalid-pp-token]
     print *,''
             ^
1 error generated.
  F90 MOD  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
../test/Fortran/test.F90:358:14: error: empty character constant [-Werror,-Winvalid-pp-token]
     print *,''
             ^
1 error generated.
  F90 USE  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
../test/Fortran/test.F90:358:14: error: empty character constant [-Werror,-Winvalid-pp-token]
     print *,''
             ^
1 error generated.

As suggested by Mr.Gilles Gouaillardet, I removed -Werror flags passed to cpp, then all errors appeared above were turned into warning, but another fatal error stops the compilation,which is
../src/elpa1/../solve_tridi/solve_tridi_template.F90:65:11:

   65 |       use merge_recursive
      |           1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'merge_recursive.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.


I have spent so much time on it. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Looks like you are using a system where mpicc and mpicxx use clang as compiler. Can you try telling MPI to use GCC?

thank you for your comments! I am using a Mac workstation, I will reconfigure it using gcc

on OSX, gcc is an alias for clang and at first glance, this is not the root cause

yes, it is difficult to convince Mac to use gcc; you have to brew-install a specific version of GCC and purposely specify it (g++-13).

@alfC I tried two methods. One is reconfigure it with CC=mpicc FC=mpif90 CXX=mpicxx replaced by CC=gcc FC=mpif90 CXX=g++ and the other is using the same configure flags and after configure, force compiler to use gcc and g++ by export MPICC=gcc export MPICXX=g++. The problem still exists.

@Gilles Gouaillardet, yes, gcc -v gives Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0

[disclaimer: I know nothing about Mac] just a remark, I find it odd that the error message comes from clang (typically a C compiler) while compiling a Fortran code. What does your mpif90 wrapper point to?

@Gilles mpif90 --version gives GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 14.1.0) 14.1.0, i think mpi fortran like mpif90 is compiled based on GNU Fortran which is included in GCC or Clang

you can try make -n to find display which command is executed.

@GillesGouaillardet make -n gives a huge amount of output in addition to the above errors.

yep, you can try make V=1 or make VERBOSE=1. I do not guarantee it will output the commands though.

@GillesGouaillardet Amazing! make V=1 gives more detailed errors information likemake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/grouphwang/softwares/elpa/elpa-2024.03.001/build'
cpp -P -traditional -Wall -Werror -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -o /dev/stdout ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90 | grep -i -o '^ use [^ ,!:]' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u > src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels-elpa2_print_kernels.use_mods_elpa2_print_kernels.o
clang: error: no input files

it seems the -o <...> option causes Apple cpp to fail with a bizarre error message. you can get rid of it, or use gcc-14 -E as a preprocessor.

first, I would try to remove -o /dev/stdout in fdep/fortran_dependencies.mk, then run autogen.sh and try again configure ... && make

@GillesGouaillardet,Sir I have removed -o /dev/stdout in fdep/fortran_dependencies.mk ,then run all autogen.sh and configure again. The above errors are resolved. Some new errors appear, like  F90 USE  [elpa2_print_kernels] ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90
F90 MOD  [elpa2_print_kernels] ../src/elpa2/elpa2_print_kernels.F90
F90 USE  [validate_complex_double_eigenvectors_1stage_analytic_all_layouts] ../test/Fortran/test.F90
../test/Fortran/test.F90:358:14: error: empty character constant [-Werror,-Winvalid-pp-token]
print *,''
^
1 error generated.

you'd have to double check the generated file and see if you spot something suspicious. note this is in a test directory and -o /dev/stdout is also present in other *.mk files related to the test, so maybe you need to remove a few more. If that still does not work or you are feeling lucky, try configure --enable-fugaku ... it seems a workaround for busted preprocessor was implemented there, so that might do the trick.

@GillesGouaillardet Sir, I use find . -name '*.mk' in the main directory and delete -o /dev/stdout in all the fortran_dependencies.mk files, but the errors still exist.

@GillesGouaillardet, Sir,configure --enable-fugaku ... doesn't work

Btw, are you running on Intel or arm?

@GillesGouaillardet Sir, my processor type is Intel Xeon W

the -Werror flag passed to cpp causes the failures. you can remove it from the same .mk file, or simply run FORTRAN_CPP="cpp -P -traditional -Wall" make

@GillesGouaillardet Thank you, Sir, you are my hero!I will try it tomorrow.

@GillesGouaillardet Good morning from South Korea, Sir, removing -Werror turns all errors into warnings, but there is fatal error which stop the compilation,like,../src/elpa1/../solve_tridi/solve_tridi_template.F90:65:11:
65 |       use merge_recursive
|           1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'merge_recursive.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

At this stage I am pretty sure ELPA is not supported on OSX. you can manually make src/solve_tridi/libelpa_private_la-mod_merge_recursive.lo src/solve_tridi/libelpa_private_la-mod_distribute_global_column.lo and then run make again. It will fail later because processor affinity is not supported on OSX, so you'll have to comment out that part.

@GillesGouaillardet Thank you very much, Sir, I give up using this library

You can open an issue here: https://gitlab.mpcdf.mpg.de/elpa/elpa/-/issues
